# PendingFileRenameOperations registry key is not cleaned up on shutdown and start

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, registry

During our upgrade scenario in our application we cannot delete some files. So in our installer we use the PendingFileRenameOperations registry key to delete those files on reboot of the system.

But strangely one of the user's system the registry key of PendingFileRenameOperations is not cleaned up on shutdown and start. I can see some other files too , not only the files from our application upgrade which are not removed.
In our development system the scenario is working fine

How can i debug/troubleshoot this scenario ? How can i find out if PendingFileRenameOperations  is working properly or not.

**UPDATE**
One interesting thing to note is that , once the users restarted the machine the entry is gone. But the next day it comes back again . User shut downs his machine every day before leaving his office.

best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Only one user? If it is an msi, I would run the msi cleanup tool. manually delete the key, reboot and reinstall. PC may be hosed, and need a reimage.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that key is only internal implementation of the OS mechanism to delete files after a reboot, not something that is intended for people to use. It's quite possible that you and the OS collided - you read, the OS reads, the OS writes, you write, and it could be corrupted in some way. Anything like that could happen,

Comment: @PhilDW...that makes sense...is there any way we can find out what is going on...can i run a process monitor on boot up and find out how the registry entries are manipulated ?

Comment: Are you actually writing directly to **PendingFileRenameOperations** yourself? Isn't that a [WRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Resource_Protection)-protected registry location that should never be written to directly? I am sure it should never be written to, but I am not sure if it is WRP protected (check with `SfcIsKeyProtected` Win32 method). MSI should handle these file deletes on its own I would believe - do you not get a prompt at the end of the install to reboot? Are these files locked by a service.exe? Did you shut down the service properly before upgrading?

Answer (score 2):

probably the user has "fast boot" enabled. 
try a full shutdown by "shutdown /s" or hold SHIFT key when clicking "SHUTDOWN" in start menu.

see  https://superuser.com/questions/495240/how-to-instruct-windows-8-not-to-perform-a-fast-shutdown