# Inno Setup: uninsrestartdelete flag doesn't work sometimes

Tags: windows, inno-setup

My application installs some dynamic libraries in the {app} folder with uninsrestartdelete flag set upon installation. After uninstallation, these locked files are all written to the registry key PendingFileRenameOperations correctly. But on some Windows 10 machines, Windows just fails to delete these files and registry values on the next reboot. I have no idea what's going wrong. Even the OS itself doesn't have enough privileges to delete these files? Thanks!

Comment: Then it does not look like Inno Setup problem. Have you googled for generic questions about `PendingFileRenameOperations`? Like [PendingFileRenameOperations registry key is not cleaned up on shutdown and start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39120130/850848).

Comment: Thanks. I've already googled for this problem. On my machine, the fast boot option is disabled and I always completely restart the machine. Very wierd! Not only my app files, even MS Office update files cannot be deleted as well. Seems the registry key is not read by Windows service on reboot at all.

Comment: Consider asking at [su] or [sf].